# Find records of any date of current month between start date and end date using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to query records that should be the month I selected and it should be between the start date and the end date.

For example,
I am storing the records below

```
Title  | start date | End Date <br>
Test 1 | 01/11/2020 | 01/11/2028 <br>
Test 2 | 22/07/2018 | 22/07/2038 <br>
Test 3 | 14/05/2005 | 14/05/2035 <br>
```

Now I want to find records for any date of the current month that lies between two start dates and end dates.

Answer (score 0):

```
  const startd = new Date(req.body.startdate); //Start date
  const endd = new Date(req.body.enddate); //end date
  Model.aggregate([
    //fetching data from your model
    { $addFields: { month: { $month: "$startdate" } } }, //new field named month, which will get month from the start date
    {
      $match: {
        month: { $gte: startd.getMonth() },//start date month
        month: { $lte: endd.getMonth() },//end date month
      },
    }, // matching start date month(month) with current date month(cmonth)
  ]);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: Dhaval How endDate should be match according to my question I need have current month data between the startDate and endDate

Comment: Check my answer i have made changes as per your requirement.